# Selenium Java - [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1]

Tags: java, arrays, selenium

Hello I'm using following method in Java Selenium. The method was working fine for a lot of sprints, then suddenly stopped to work throwing following error: *The Operation failed. Page Control: pagecontrols.CustomMethods, operation: getNumberOfElements, cause: [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1]*

I found similar cases however I'm not able to compare them to my own method:

```
public int getNumberOfElements(){
    List<WebElement> childs = webDriver.findElements(By.xpath(webElement.toString().split(" -> xpath: ")[1].replaceFirst("(?s)(.*)\\]", "$1" + "")));
    int numofChildren = childs.size();
    return numofChildren;
    }
```

I understood that error is generated by accessing array with illegal index so I've chagned: `(By.xpath(webElement.toString().split(" -> xpath: ")[0]` <- to 0 Since thereshall be only one element in the array. But it still does not work. I have no ideas what I can change in context of this error.

Regards

Comment: Are you sure the string contains a literal `>` and not something like `&gt;`? More generally, what is `webElement`?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca my webelements are: //div[@id='mainProducts' and @role='listbox']//following-sibling::div[@style='background-color: white;'] 
however there is only one webelement like this visible on the screen while performing this method.